# mysql - unique index with nulls - actual solution anyone?

Tags: mysql, null, unique-constraint

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS b2c_constants (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    is_deleted BOOL DEFAULT FALSE,
    UNIQUE (name)
) ENGINE InnoDB CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS b2c_constant_bindings (
    constant_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    company_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    object_id INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    property_id INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    value VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (constant_id, company_id, object_id, property_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (constant_id) REFERENCES b2c_constants (id) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES companies (id) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (object_id) REFERENCES b2b_objects (id) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (property_id) REFERENCES b2b_properties (id) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE InnoDB CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

The problem is with the unique key in the `bindings` table. If I have data like:

```
constant_id   company_id   object_id   property_id   value
1             1            null        null          foo
1             1            1           null          bar
1             1            1           1             baz
```

You can duplicate the first two rows without any errors infinitely, which is obviously not desirable.

The idea with this structure is to allow to bind constants globally per company, per object in company, and per property in company, but allow only unique constants for each of those.

Is there a way to solve this in the database while keeping the foreign keys and a simple table structure? I know that I could do `type ENUM ('company', 'object', 'property'), type_id INT`, but with that I lose the foreign keys as well as the required company ID for all constants.

Comment: Why not use `NOT NULL DEFAULT ''`?Mysql treats NULLs as different,even from each other, in an unique index

Comment: agree, but because it INT - DEFAULT 0 will be better. 0 not allowed in parent table and could work as NULL in binding table fine.

Comment: `FOREIGN KEYs` do not fit all situations.

Comment: You really ought to have an explicit `PRIMARY KEY` on every InnoDB table.

Comment: @Mihai - `NOT NULL DEFAULT anything` does not work with foreign keys.

Comment: @RickJames - irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @jurchiks about "irrelevant". While I disagree with RickJames, it's his claim and very much relevant to the question (which is after all about unique indexes and foreign keys)

Comment: Also there are 3 more tables in your design which you don't show. Please add them in the question.

Comment: Those 3 tables can be made by yourself, just give them a single ID column and that's it. Their structure does not add to the question in any way.

Comment: Oh they do matter. We could guess of course but we may get the FKs differently than what you have. If you don't care about getting decent answers ...

Comment: You must be pretty special then. How does this improve the question? https://gist.github.com/jurchiks/a472a9eaf87ae635a30326cab720fb57

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**[This is not tested as it requires MySQL 5.7.6 or above]**

While I agree with the comments above, I still have an idea that can be tried, which I think is not the best in terms of performance, but it solves the issue you're describing.

The idea is to add a key that deals with `NULL` as a concrete value, like '0', or any other value. Then, uniquely index the combination of the fields that you want to be unique.

MySQL 5.7.6 supports [generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html).

```
ALTER TABLE b2c_constant_bindings
ADD unique_md5 char(32) AS 
    (MD5(CONCAT_WS('X', ifnull(constant_id, 0), ifnull(company_id, 0), ifnull(object_id, 0), ifnull(property_id,0)))) 
    UNIQUE;
```

Instead of using `CONCAT`, I am using `CONCAT_WS` to avoid having same results in cases similar to `CONCAT(1, 23)` and `CONCAT(12, 3)` (ss per @Rick James' notice).

Comment: If you are going to use `CHAR` for hex characters, be sure to say `CHARACTER SET ascii` for the column.

Comment: It will still produce the same hash for `CONCAT_WS('X', 1, 2, NULL, 3)` and `CONCAT_WS('X', 1, 2, 3, NULL)` but based on the sample data and structure we could assume that such data is not intended to appear (despite there is no constraint to enforce it)

Comment: My main idea, that I skipped, is to use `IFNULL` function. I edited the question

Comment: I'll check this tomorrow, thanks! The performance in this case isn't that important as the inserts won't be very frequent.

Comment: Ok, so the task was delayed and I only got to checking this today, but there's a problem - the SQL statement you provided does not work for me: `#1904 - Key/Index cannot be defined on a non-stored computed column`. I am using MariaDB 10.1.18, and it is supposed to work for me: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/virtual-computed-columns/ Supposedly it didn't work up until 10.1.6, but should work afterwards, with some limitations which don't affect me. The exact same error appears if I add the column without index and then the index separately, so the problem is in the UNIQUE index.

Comment: Edit: just add `PERSISTENT` before `UNIQUE` and it works. MariaDB 10.1.18 doesn't support the `STORED` keyword, it was only added in 10.2.1.